# Can I put a 3-gang box and a 2-gang box (Old Construction) just next to each other to make a 5-gang box?

Tags: electrical

Home Depot doesn't seem to have 5-gang boxes - can I put a 3-gang and a 2-gang box together assuming that existing wiring reaches as required?

Comment: What, do you have a big Home Depot gift card you have to use up? Any electrical supply house.  They'll be cheaper too on this odd stuff.

Comment: If HD is your only option then they can order it for you.  --https://www.homedepot.com/p/Madison-Electric-Products-Smart-Box-5-Gang-Multi-Mount-Adjustable-Depth-Device-Box-MSBMMT5G/203343451   -   If you put two together then the spacing will not be right for the cover plate to line up for all switches. They do make modular  ones so you daisy chain several together.

Comment: @AlaskaMan  Type this up as an answer.

Comment: @JACK Let pause a moment for the mans prayer:  I'm a man, but i can change, if i have to, i guess !

Answer (score 7):

If HD is your only option then they can order it for you. [Here is one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Madison-Electric-Products-Smart-Box-5-Gang-Multi-Mount-Adjustable-Depth-Device-Box-MSBMMT5G/203343451) -

If you put two together then the spacing will not be right for the cover plate to line up for all switches.

They do make modular ones so you can daisy chain several together, I have seen them a lowes but i can not find a link.

You may need to go to a dedicated electrical supply house.